# How to calculate the pitch of the quadcopter rotor blade and their efficiency?

Tags: quadcopter, first-robotics, multi-rotor, drone

I have gone to some of the blade designs and profiles of the blade which suits my requirement. But, once after entering the Theoretical calculation, I was stuck in the determination or the Justification for the Magnitude of Pitch mentioned in the Blade.

Example: I have taken the propeller of size 10 inch and 4.5-inch pitch value, Some blogs suggested to have a pitch of 0.2 times of the propeller dia for stable and efficient flight. But they didn't reveal how it affected the efficiency or why they stated those values...?

Comment: Could you add the references to "Justification for the Magnitude of Pitch" or "Blade". Do they refer to some common terminology among hobby-builders.

Comment: https://robu.in/product/orange-hd-propellers-60456x4-5-carbon-fiber-nylon-props/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6PD3BRDPARIsAN8pHuGE8aI-5KB073Cfkd52DoRV6aLaW-WfafuT4n2yA6WX0mzb_byXWvoaArWYEALw_wcB
I have mentioned the link for the chosen propeller and in this, they have specified the pitch of 4.5 inches and I want to know how they found it out

Answer (score 1):

Not long ago I had the same problem of evaluating different blade designs. Well it's  not an easy task. I used [JavaProp](http://If%20you%20want%20do%20evaluate) which is a tool for evaluating propeller designs. The author has an phd in aerdynamics so I guess the tool works properly. It allows you to caluclate the efficency depending on the pitch angles, altitude, cruising speed, rpm, motor torque etc.

Comment: I have seen the reference you have mentioned, but the article is mainly focused on the ship propellers and jet aircrafts

Comment: With the tool I mentioned, you can evaluate airscrews in general . The way they generate thrust is independant of the angle of attack. Have a look at VTOL aircrafts. I agree that there is a difference between aero and hydrodynamics, but the working peinciple is the same. As an extra option you can evaluate turbofans which are a special case of airscrews / Propellers